# AoT version of my app throws "require is not defined"

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I have followed [the official AoT tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) and everything (compilation & server launch) worked. However, when I load the app on my browser, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at main-aot.js:2
    at main-aot.js:4
```

In the `main-aot.js`, I have the following: `var platform_browser_1 = require('@angular/platform-browser');`

I kind of understand why I'm getting this error... I never load any support for the require function (my JiT app uses systemJS) but in the tutorial nothing is mentioned about this `require`. Please note that I have copied (letter for letter) all the AoT files (main-aot.ts, rollup-config.js and tsconfig-aot.json)

What am I missing here?

Comment: All articles I can find on AOT specifically state that require is not possible.

Comment: @MikeOne interesting... I guess I have a problem when typescript transpile into javascript! Any suggestion on what I should get instead of a require and how I can fix that?

Comment: I use webpack my self, not much experience with systemJS. But I think the clue is to not use a 'dynamic' link like require. So either typescript kind of imports, or import via your loader (so they are precompiled with your code instead of imported dynamically). So it depends on your setup I guess. Is there an option to go the Angular-cli / webpack route? Because AOT will definitely work (easier) there.

Comment: @MikeOne I'm not very comfortable with the loaders so I don't know exactly how to implement a solution for the AoT... what surprises me is that nothing is mentioned in the tutorial about loaders. So I guess I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what!

Comment: I wonder if maybe you have some JavaScript files that got transpiled before you ran the AoT build? If you're using Visual Studio, sometimes it tries to 'help' and transpile in the background. That might explain why you're getting the ES5/commonjs version with the 'require' statements. Rollup needs them to be in ES2015. try deleting your transpiled js/js.map files and running it again.